# Invalid capture filter

Tags: c#, tshark

Im getting the error : "tshark: Invalid capture filter "> test1.txt" for interface NetToAutomationSlave!"

```
private void OpenTWireShark()
    {
        string path = string.Format(@"-i 3 -Y ip.src==192.168.20.100 > test1.txt"); 
        ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        cmdStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe";
        cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmdStartInfo.Arguments = path;

        Process cmdProcess = new Process();
        cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
        cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
        cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;

        cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        cmdProcess.Start();

        cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

        cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot redirect the standard Output using `> test1.txt` as argument.
You need to use data from the `OutputDataReceived` event and log this to your txtfile

Comment: when Im trying to read from the OutputDataReceived  im getting only the line number and not the filter . ??? for example: if im trying this line as an argument : "-i 3 -Y ip.src==192.168.20.100" the output in getting is "1"